# Checking to see if an area of the screen changes

Tags: c#

I'm testing some methods for checking if an area of the screen changes, can you see any problems with how I'm doing this, and is there a better way for me to do this?

the `_memoryImage2` will not change in the final app, it will be a read only array that I will check the `memoryImage` against.

```
namespace ScreenShot_BoundsTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Bitmap _memoryImage1;
        Bitmap _memoryImage2;

        Color[,] _first;
        Color[,] _second;

        private string _valueX;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void GetImage()
        {
            _memoryImage2 = _memoryImage1;
            CaptureScreen();
            pictureBox2.Image = pictureBox1.Image;
            if (_memoryImage1 != null) _first = Bitmap2Imagearray(_memoryImage1);

            pictureBox1.Image = _memoryImage1;
            if (_memoryImage2 != null) _second = Bitmap2Imagearray(_memoryImage2);

            var x = CompareArrays();

            _valueX = x != true ? "false" : "true";
        }

        private bool CompareArrays()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < _memoryImage1.Width; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < _memoryImage1.Height; j++)
                {
                    if (_first == null) continue;
                    if (_second != null)
                        if (_first[i,j] != _second[i,j])
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                }
            }
            return _first != null && _second != null;
        }

        private void CaptureScreen()
        {
            Size s;
            using (var myGraphics = CreateGraphics())
            {
                s = new Size(100, 50);
                _memoryImage1 = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
            }

            var memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(_memoryImage1);
            memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(100, 100, 10, 10, s);
        }

        private static Color[,] Bitmap2Imagearray(Bitmap b)
        {
            var imgArray = new Color[b.Width, b.Height];
            for (var y = 0; y < b.Height; y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < b.Width; x++)
                {
                    imgArray[x, y] = b.GetPixel(x, y);
                }
            }
            return imgArray;
        }

        private void BackgroundWorker1DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            GetImage();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        private void BackgroundWorker1RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = _valueX;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start with your algorithm. You're using `Bitmap.GetPixel` to convert the entire bitmap image pixel by pixel into matrix of colors. I tried this approach several years ago - it was pretty slow on .Net 2.0 and I suppose it is still slow. You should convert image into `byte[]` and extract color bytes out of this array, it should be hundred times faster. Look into [Bitmap.Lockbits method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx) and [BitmapData class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.aspx).

Remaining points are about your code readability. There are several general rules which may improve readability a lot:

1. If method has some result of execution then **return this result** instead of assigning it to some field. Also use method parameters to accept arguments instead of class fields.
2. If variable is not needed outside of one method's scope then **do not declare a field** for it, **use local variable** instead.
3. Be **strongly typed**. Do not cast anything to string until you really need string.

These simple rules being applied to your code mean:

1. Rules **#1** and **#3** mean that your methods should have following signature:

   - **void GetImage()** -> **bool CompareCurrentImageWithPrevious()**
   - **bool CompareArrays()** -> **static bool CompareImageArrays(Color[,] imageArray1, Color[,] imageArray2)**
   - **void CaptureScreen()** -> **Bitmap CaptureScreen()**
2. This

   ```
   var x = CompareArrays();
   _valueX = x != true ? "false" : "true";
   ```

   Should be replaced with:

   ```
   return CompareArrays();
   ```
3. This

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < _memoryImage1.Width; i++)
   {
       for (var j = 0; j < _memoryImage1.Height; j++)
       {
           if (_first == null) continue;
           if (_second != null)
               if (_first[i,j] != _second[i,j])
               {
                   return false;
               }
       }
   }
   return _first != null && _second != null;
   ```

   Should be:

   ```
    if (_first == null || _second == null) return false;
    if (_memoryImage1.Width != _memoryImage2.Width ||
        _memoryImage1.Height != _memoryImage2.Height)
        return false;
    return _first.SequenceEquals(_second);
   ```
4. Do not assign result of `GetImage()` to class field, `DoWorkEventArgs` have `Result` property which can be used to return value computed by background worker.

   ```
   private void BackgroundWorker1DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   {
       e.Result = GetImage();
       Thread.Sleep(100);
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you very mutch, it was realy helpful :) I will implement the changes and start using the ways you describe in future projects. +1 for helping in making me a better developer.